# How to code timer in a reminder app for android?

Tags: android, timer, reminders

I am a student learning android programming. Currently, I am making a reminder app where a user is allowed to enter 3 times using a time picker for a certain day. He will be reminded about something on these times. I am storing these data in the database. The user also selects days when he wishes to be reminded on and not dates. My question is that how to set the timer in the service that can retrieve the data check if its the particular day and then fire an alarm for that. Below is the code that I have tried. It works but I want to code a better efficient program. I am not satisfied with my coding.

Below is my code:

**MY DATABASE CLASS**

```
//this is my database
String reminderCreateQuery = "CREATE TABLE reminders" +
                    "(_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
                    "message TEXT" +
                    "hour1 INTEGER, min1 INTEGER, hour2 INTEGER, min2 INTEGER, hour3 INTEGER, min3 INTEGER," +
                    "AllDays INTEGER, Sun INTEGER, Mon INTEGER, Tue INTEGER, Wed INTEGER, Thu INTEGER, Fri INTEGER, Sat INTEGER);";

//this is where I am inserting my data in the database
public void insertReminder(String message, int hour1, int min1, int hour2,
                                   int min2, int hour3, int min3, int AllDays, int Sun, int Mon, int Tue, int Wed,
                                   int Thu, int Fri, int Sat) {
        ContentValues newReminder = new ContentValues();
        newReminder.put("message", message);
        newReminder.put("hour1", hour1);
        newReminder.put("min1", min1);
        newReminder.put("hour2", hour2);
        newReminder.put("min2", min2);
        newReminder.put("hour3", hour3);
        newReminder.put("min3", min3);
        newReminder.put("Sun", Sun);
        newReminder.put("Mon", Mon);
        newReminder.put("Tue", Tue);
        newReminder.put("Wed", Wed);
        newReminder.put("Thu", Thu);
        newReminder.put("Fri", Fri);
        newReminder.put("Sat", Sat);
        newReminder.put("AllDays", AllDays);
        open();
        reminderdatabase.insert("reminders", null, newReminder);
        close();
    }

//this is where i am updating my data in the database

public void updateReminder(long id, String message,int hour1, int min1, int hour2,
                                   int min2, int hour3, int min3, int AllDays, int Sun, int Mon, int Tue, int Wed,
                                   int Thu, int Fri, int Sat) {
        ContentValues editReminder = new ContentValues();
        editReminder.put("message", message);
        editReminder.put("hour1", hour1);
        editReminder.put("min1", min1);
        editReminder.put("hour2", hour2);
        editReminder.put("min2", min2);
        editReminder.put("hour3", hour3);
        editReminder.put("min3", min3);
        editReminder.put("Sun", Sun);
        editReminder.put("Mon", Mon);
        editReminder.put("Tue", Tue);
        editReminder.put("Wed", Wed);
        editReminder.put("Thu", Thu);
        editReminder.put("Fri", Fri);
        editReminder.put("Sat", Sat);
        editReminder.put("AllDays", AllDays);

        open();
        reminderdatabase.update("reminders", editReminder, "_id=" + id, null);
        close();
    }

    //this gets called in AsynClass where it returns the cursor
public Cursor getSundayReminders() {

        return remindersdatabase.query("reminders", null, "Sun = ?", new String[] {"1"}, null, null,null);
    }
```

**MY ACTIVITY CLASS**

```
//this is where i am saving or editing my data in the database

private void saveReminder() {
        DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);
        if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
            databaseConnector.insertReminder(
                    MessageNameLabe.getText().toString(),
                    hour1, minute1, hour2, minute2, hour3, minute3,
                    Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat);

        } else {
            databaseConnector.updateReminder(rowID,
                    MessageNameLabe.getText().toString(),
                    hour1, minute1, hour2, minute2, hour3, minute3,
                    Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat);
        }
        startMyAlarm();
    }

    public void startMyAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyReminderAddActivity.this, SetMyAlarm.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

**MY SERVICE CLASS**

```
// I have a timer that calls a function getmyDays() in my service..This function gets called in saveReminder() function

public void startTimer() {
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                checkMyDays();
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 3600000);
    }

//checkMyDays() checks the day for today...I have only put the example for Sunday
public void checkMyDays() {
        if (checkdays.isTodaySunday()) {
            todayIsSunday = true;
            todayIsMonday = todayIsTuesday = todayIsWednesday = todayIsThrusday = todayIsFriday = todayIsSaturday = false;
        }
         getMyDays();
    }

//isTodaySunday() is just a function that checks todays day...I have only put the example for Sunday
public boolean isTodaySunday(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY;
    }


//my database function where sunday is 1
 public void getMyDays() {
        if (todayIsSunday) {
            new GetReminderSundayTask().execute();
        }
    }


//here i am getting data from the database

private class GetReminderSundayTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> {
        DatabaseConnector prescriptiondatabaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(SetMyAlarm.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params) {
            remindersdatabaseConnector.open();

            return remindersdatabaseConnector.getSundayReminders();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            boolean data = result.moveToFirst();
            while (data) {
                int hour1Index = result.getColumnIndex("hour1");
                Hour1 = result.getInt(hour1Index);

                int min1Index = result.getColumnIndex("min1");
                Minute1 = result.getInt(min1Index);

                int hour2Index = result.getColumnIndex("hour2");
                Hour2 = result.getInt(hour2Index);

                int min2Index = result.getColumnIndex("min2");
                Minute2 = result.getInt(min2Index);

                int hour3Index = result.getColumnIndex("hour3");
                Hour3 = result.getInt(hour3Index);

                int min3Index = result.getColumnIndex("min3");
                Minute3 = result.getInt(min3Index);

                getMyMillis(Hour1, Minute1, Hour2, Minute2, Hour3, Minute3);

                if (timeInMilliSeconds1 > 0) {
                    Time1List.add(timeInMilliSecondsDosage1);
                    countTime1++;
                }
                if (timeInMilliSeconds2 > 0) {
                    Time2List.add(timeInMilliSecondsDosage2);
                    countForTime2++;
                }
                if (timeInMilliSeconds3 > 0) {
                    Time3List.add(timeInMilliSecondsDosage3);
                    countForTime3++;
                }
                int messageIndex = result.getColumnIndex("message");
                messageList.add(result.getString(messageIndex));
                count++;
                countIDList.add(count);
                data = result.moveToNext();
            }
            Log.d("My Alarm", "Count is " + count);
            result.close();
            remindersdatabaseConnector.close();
            startMyAlarm();
        }
    }


    // here I am converting my hour and min to millis
    public void getMyMillis(int hour1, int minute1, int hour2, int minute2, int hour3, int minute3) {
        if (hour1 != 0 && minute1 != 0) {
            CalendarTime1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
            CalendarTime1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute1);
            timeInMilliSeconds1 = CalendarTime1.getTimeInMillis();
        } else {
            timeInMilliSeconds1 = 0;
        }
        if (hour2 != 0 && minute2 != 0) {
            CalendarTime2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour2);
            CalendarTime2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute2);
            timeInMilliSeconds2 = CalendarTime2.getTimeInMillis();
        } else {
            timeInMilliSeconds2 = 0;
        }

        if (hour3 != 0 && minute3 != 0) {
            CalendarTime3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour3);
            CalendarTime3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute3);
            timeInMilliSeconds3 = CalendarTime3.getTimeInMillis();
        } else {
            timeInMilliSeconds3 = 0;
        }
    }


//then in starMyAlarm() I fire my alarms
public void startMyAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        if (countForTime1 > 0) {
            AlarmManager[] alarmMgrForTime1 = new AlarmManager[countForTime1];
            for (int i = 0; i < countForTime1.size(); i++) {
                if (Time1List != null) {
                    if (i < Time1List.size()) {
                        timeInMilliSeconds1 = Time1List.get(i);
                        if (timeInMilliSeconds1 > 0) {
                            firstTimedentifierList.add(firstTimeIdentifier);
                            intent.putExtra("TimeIdentifier", 1);
                            alarmIntentForTime1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarmRequestCodeForTime1, intent, 0);
                            alarmMgrForTime1[i] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmMgrForTime1[i].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilliSeconds1, alarmIntentForTime1);
                            alarmRequestCodeListForTime1.add(alarmRequestCodeForTime1);
                            intentArrayListForTime1.add(alarmIntentForTime1);
                            alarmRequestCodeForTime1++;
                            firstTimeIdentifier++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (countForTime2 > 0) {
            AlarmManager[] alarmMgrForTime2 = new AlarmManager[countForTime2];
            for (int i = 0; i < countForTime2.size(); i++) {
                if (Time2List != null) {
                    if (i < Time2List.size()) {
                        timeInMilliSeconds2 = Time2List.get(i);
                        if (timeInMilliSeconds2 > 0) {
                            secondTimedentifierList.add(secondTimeIdentifier);
                            intent.putExtra("TimeIdentifier", 2);
                            alarmIntentForTime2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarmRequestCodeForTime2, intent, 0);
                            alarmMgrForTime2[i] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmMgrForTime2[i].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilliSeconds2, alarmIntentForTime2);
                            alarmRequestCodeListForTime2.add(alarmRequestCodeForTime2);
                            intentArrayListForTime2.add(alarmIntentForTime2);
                            alarmRequestCodeForTime2++;
                            secondTimeIdentifier++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (countForTime3> 0) {
            AlarmManager[] alarmMgrForTime3 = new AlarmManager[countForTime3];
            for (int i = 0; i < countForTime3.size(); i++) {
                if (Time3List != null) {
                    if (i < Time3List.size()) {
                        timeInMilliSeconds3 = Time3List.get(i);
                        if (timeInMilliSeconds3 > 0) {
                            thirdTimedentifierList.add(thirdTimeIdentifier);
                            intent.putExtra("TimeIdentifier", 3);
                            alarmIntentForTime3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarmRequestCodeForTime3, intent, 0);
                            alarmMgrForTime1[i] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            alarmMgrForTime1[i].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilliSeconds3, alarmIntentForTime3);
                            alarmRequestCodeListForTime3.add(alarmRequestCodeForTime3);
                            intentArrayListForTime3.add(alarmIntentForTime3);
                            alarmRequestCodeForTime3++;
                            thirdTimeIdentifier++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Should I have two tables one for data and one for alarms. How will I cancel a particular alarm after deleting data from the database? I have already saved the intent of it but how will I know which alarm got deleted and how it matches which intent in the database? Is there a better way of doing the timer for this alarm?

I haven't studied database course yet. So I having difficulty with databases. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use AlarmManager and Broadcast receiver

Comment: Yeah I am using alarm manager.

Comment: Yes you should save alarms in another table/column.You can cancel the alarm using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)